# Excel 2013: Meta Data details in Header

Tags: xml, excel, ms-office, apache-poi

I’m trying to add identifiers to specific words within the  XML element of an Excel 2013 document.

**Why?** I need to have a program that can export and import excel documents with variables included in the header. Currently, my program does something like the following:

[image: Export Flow]

**What I’ve tried:** Already, I’ve attempted to put customized xml elements around the variable strings within the Excel’s sheet1 XML data (“myvar” element with a “name” attribute):

*myspreadsheet.xlsx/worksheets/sheet1.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
…
<headerFooter>
    <oddHeader>My project  is <myvar name=”ProjectName”>APL</myvar>, managed by <myvar name=”ManagerName”>John Doe</myvar></oddHeader>
</headerFooter>
…
```

...However, Microsoft strips off my added “myvar” elements.

**The question:** How can I identify each variable I used for the output of my header so I can import it back in with their variable names intact? Import back as “My project is $ProjectName, managed by $ManagerName.”?

(I use apache-poi for document writing/reading)

Comment: Why not just put `$ProjectName` into the file, then use Apache POI to get the header string, search+replace on that, and then store the updated header back?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Gagravarr! The objective I'm trying to achieve is not to have any of those variable names show up in the written document (just their values), but to still be able to identify which words were variables so I can import them back to my program as such - even if the header was edited in MS Excel before the import.